# Primitive calculator - Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

So, the problem task is:

> Given an integer , compute the minimum number of operations needed
> to obtain the number  starting from the number 1.

And here is my code for doing this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n+1);
    for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        v[i] = 0;
    }
    v[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= v.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if((v[i + 1] == 0) || (v[i + 1] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[i + 1] = v[i] + 1;
        }
        if((2*i <= n) && (v[2*i] == 0 || v[2*i] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[2*i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
        if((3*i <= n) && (v[3*i] == 0 || v[3*i] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[3*i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
    }
    vector<int> solution;
    while(n > 1)
    {
        solution.push_back(n);
        if(v[n - 1] == v[n] - 1)
        {
            n = n-1;
        }
        else if(n%2 == 0 && v[n/2] == v[n] - 1)
        {
            n = n/2;
        }
        else if(n%3 == 0 && v[n/3] == v[n] - 1)
        {
            n = n/3;
        }
    }
    solution.push_back(1);
    reverse(solution.begin(), solution.end());
    for(size_t k = 0; k < solution.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << solution[k] << ' ';
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out any mistake. This is not giving me any output. It will be great if you could help me out.
Input and output have been shown here:

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
3
1 2 4 5
```

So, basically you have to give number of operations needed to do this task for n and provide the sequence of intermediate numbers.

Comment: Did you debug? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Can you please post input/output and expected input/output

Comment: What operations are valid? And before coding it in C++, what algorithm do you plan to use?

Comment: Unrelated: `i <= v.size() - 1` can be expressed more readable as `i < v.size()`

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I tried debugging but could not find my fault.

Comment: I have posted input/output now.

Comment: Side note: `std::vector(n+1, 0)` initalises the vector to all 0 and you don't need the loop...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I want to use dynamic programming for this, greedy will not provide me correct answer.

Comment: Please don't ever [`include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @imgeek_ You can't be using a debugger correctly, your code has immediate and obvious errors.

Comment: @Aconcagua But why is this, I am kinda new to cpp. It will be great if you could explain a  bit.

Comment: @imgeek_ It is explained in the link provided. In short: This is a GCC-specific header not intended for inclusion and other compilers don't provide it. So you have non-portable code.

Comment: What actually is the meaning of `number n`?

Comment: @Aconcagua number n means any integer which you want to reach from 1 with three operations, namely, +1, X2 and X3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pretty blatant out of bounds accesses on your vector `v`.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= v.size() - 1; i++)
    ,,,
    v[3*i] = v[i] + 1;
```

`3*i` is obviously bigger than the size of `v` for most of your loop.

Comment: Yeah, I accept that! I have modified this code by adding conditions like 3*i <= n etc.

Comment: I got that! I added this line and bingo!